# How to control a react-select component from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-select

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension to automate the filling out of a new issue in Jira, and in order to do this, I need to control a `react-select` component from my `content_script`. These are very tricky beasts indeed since they are made up of lots of divs within which is an actual input (that is often hidden until you click on it).

I've created a small [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-select-manual-test-7lz583) which has a basic `react-select` example and a button that sets focus to the input and types the letters "Red" to filter the options. I've sprinkled lots of timeouts in there to slow it down in case I need to wait for things to process before I can type (such as focusing the input field), but my experiments have been futile.

In the basic example I copied from the [react-select site](https://react-select.com/home#getting-started), the hidden input field is in the DOM at all times (thankfully), but it doesn't appear in Jira until you click on it (alas!). So that will be another challenge, but even in this basic example, I can't even get it to work.

Is it possible to simulate user clicks and keyboard events like this, or is this behaviour seen as potentially suspicious and deliberately blocked by the browser? Am I asking the impossible?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: Thank you very much, wOxxOm, that works nicely. I've updated the codesandbox demo above to use your solution. I guess it's safe enough to use this method until something better comes along.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simplified example of how you might approach this using JavaScript in your content script. This assumes that you've already injected your content script into the page and have access to the DOM:

```
// Function to simulate a click event
function simulateClick(element) {
  const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window,
  });
  element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}

// Function to simulate typing into an input field
function simulateTyping(element, text) {
  element.value = text;
  const inputEvent = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
  });
  element.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
}

// Assuming `reactSelect` is the react-select component

// Simulate click to make the input visible
simulateClick(reactSelect);

// Wait for the input to become visible (you might need to adjust the delay)
setTimeout(() => {
  // Find the input field (adjust the selector as needed)
  const inputField = document.querySelector('.react-select__input input');

  // Simulate typing into the input field
  simulateTyping(inputField, 'Red');
}, 1000); // Adjust the delay as needed
```

Remember that this is a simplified example, and you may need to adapt it based on the specific structure and behavior of the react-select component in Jira. Additionally, be cautious about potential changes to the website's structure or behavior, as it might break your automation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: This doesn't work either, although judging from DavidW's comment above, it's an AI-generated answer anyway.